# How do you create a function that will return the sum, average, minimum value, and maximum value of a integer array using tuple as return type?

Tags: arrays, swift, function, tuples

The min and max function already worked, but I don't know how to add a function for sum and average of the integer array.

Here is my code:

```swift
func minMax(array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int) {
    var currentMin = array[0]
    var currentMax = array[0]
    for value in array[1..<array.count] {
        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
        } else if value > currentMax {
            currentMax = value
        }
    }
    return (currentMin, currentMax)
}

let bounds = minMax(array: [8, -6, 2, 109, 3, 71])
print("min is \(bounds.min) and max is \(bounds.max)") //outputs min is -6 and max is 109
```

Comment: It looks like your function signature is cut-off in your code, I assume it's something like `func minMax(array: [Int]) -> (min: Int, max: Int)`.  Are you saying that you need it to return a tuple of four values instead of two?

Comment: As an aside, your function will crash for empty arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array : [Int] = [8, -6, 3, 109, 3, 71]


func foo(array : [Int]) -> (Int, Float, (Int, Int)){
    let sum  : Int = array.reduce(0, +)
    let avg : Float = Float(sum)/Float(array.count)
    let min : Int = array.min()!
    let max : Int = array.max()!
    return (sum, avg, (min, max))
}

//if u want add this nil checking inside the function
if array.count != 0{
    print(foo(array: array)) // (188, 31.333334, (-6, 109))

}
```